# Python Simulate jQuery on webpage

Tags: jquery, python, post

Hello once again stackoverflow community.  I have yet another question for something I am working on.  Currently, in Python, I'm working on a simple chat bot to expand my knowledge of Python.  On the website I am testing it on, it appears they use entirely jQuery for their chat box.

For example, the jQuery that allows submitting text in their chat-box looks like this:

```
("#chat_speak").on("click",function(){CurrentChat.chat_say()})
```

How could I, preferably using the requests library, simulate a function such as 'CurrentChat.chat_say()', or, figure out what POST request to send to achieve the same result as this function would.

Any help on this issue is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Requests is just a really nice HTTP library. It doesn't execute JavaScript, so there's no way for it to actually do this.

You'll need to use another HTTP library that supports JavaScript, like [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/), which is a headless WebKit browser.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, I'll see if the Ghost.py library helps in my issues at all.